# Unable to share photo using Open Graph on Android Application (Android Studio)

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-opengraph

I have got the following issue when trying to share an image...

I am able to share an OpenGraph on my application through the code:

Set the permissions -

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
                        thisActivity,
                        Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

Them creates and shares the OpenGraph -

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                        .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
                        .putString("og:title", "Sample Course")
                        .putString("og:description", "This is a sample course.")
                        .putInt("fitness:duration:value", 100)
                        .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
                        .putInt("fitness:distance:value", 12)
                        .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
                        .putInt("fitness:speed:value", 5)
                        .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
                        .build();
                ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                        .setActionType("fitness.runs")
                        .putObject("fitness:course", object)
                        .build();
                ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                        .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
                        .setAction(action)
                        .build();
shareDialog.show(thisActivity, content);
```

But when I try to attach a picture to the Open Graph I get the error:

> Unable to show the provided content via the web or the installed
>   version of the Facebook app. Some dialogs are only supported starting
>   API 14.

The code I am using to attach the pic is:

First, creates the photo object -

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                        .setBitmap(bitmapLogoPhoto)
                        .build();
```

Then creates and shares the Open Graph object (the only difference from the above code is that I use .putPhoto("image", photo) to include the photo to ShareOpenGraphPhoto):

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                        .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
                        .putString("og:title", "Sample Course")
                        .putString("og:description", "This is a sample course.")
                        .putInt("fitness:duration:value", 100)
                        .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
                        .putInt("fitness:distance:value", 12)
                        .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
                        .putInt("fitness:speed:value", 5)
                        .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
                        .build();
                ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                        .setActionType("fitness.runs")
                        .putObject("fitness:course", object)
                        .putPhoto("image", photo)
                        .build();
                ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                        .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
                        .setAction(action)
                        .build();


                shareDialog.show(thisActivity, content);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance